# instanceof with custom/core classes

Tags: java, instanceof

Why can I test my custom class against my custom interface using `instanceof` and I am unable to do the same with java core classes?

```
interface A{}
class B{}
public class Tmp {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String s = "";
        Integer i = 1;
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(s instanceof A); //1
        System.out.println(i instanceof A); //2
        System.out.println(b instanceof A); //3
    }
}
```

Lines 1 and 2 won't compile. Line 3 will compile (and print `false`). What's the difference?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) article?

Comment: @Bernard, yes I have read this. It didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the compiler can detect that the `instanceof` operation could never be true it will generate a compiler error. It determines this by following the same rules as that for casting. The specific rule is described in [Section 15.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) of the JLS:

> If a cast of the RelationalExpression to the ReferenceType would be
>   rejected as a compile-time error, then the instanceof relational
>   expression likewise produces a compile-time error. In such a
>   situation, the result of the instanceof expression could never be
>   true.

Comment: Yes, I understand it now! It's because both `String` and `Integer` are final classes and thus an object referenced by `String` or `Integer` can never ever implement `A`. `B` (or `HashMap`) are not final so their subclasses might implement `A` so compiler can not be sure that such comparison is pointless.